# Sending Contact Form Emails

Tags: 8, forms, emails, configuration

I am trying to configure a site to send emails using the Contact Us form. At the moment, my understanding is that some PHP modules are required for that. I have already created the Contact Us forms and entered the 'recepient' addresses.

Could someone tell me how I should configure the PHP to do that? The site is running PHP 7.0.12

Comment: _At the moment, my understanding is that some PHP modules are required for that._ Can you elaborate why you think that and what modules you mean in particular? If this is really about PHP configuration, it would be considered off-topic here because that is in the realm of server configuration, not Drupal.

Comment: I bought this theme from a 3rd party and their support mentioned this. The question is about getting Drupal 8 to send emails.

Comment: As it is currently written, the question is about configuring PHP. If you believe it is different, please add details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on localhost there is a great chance your emails will not be sent.

I would recommend using [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) for your form modules as this is a very good tool for this.

And test the email part on an actual server. If you want to send emails locally you will need to set up your php.ini file:

See more info on that here: [explanation here](https://www.drupal.org/node/261008)

Comment: I am running the site on a Linux instance on AWS. Does that change anything?

Comment: I am not familliar with AWS, so i can't help you with that. 
But you can contact AWS and they can probably help you out!
Hope this is enough info for you.